# Entity Framework add object to related entity without loading

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I would like to add an object to a related entity without loading them.
I have Company entity defined like this:

```
public class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> EmployeeList{ get; set; }       

}
```

And Employee entity like this

```
    public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name{ get; set; }       
}
```

I want to add an employee to a list placed in that company object without loading all the employees.

I know I can use this expression 
`Company myCompany= systemBD.Companies.Include("EmployeeList").Find(1) myCompany.EmployeeList.Add(newEmployee)`
 but I'm afraid that this would consume a lot of time since I have thousands of employees in my database.

Is there a way to add a new employee to an existing company without loading the list of Employees?
I was looking into the Attach method but it does not seem to work.

```
        using (var systemDB = new CompanyDB())
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee ();                
            Company companySearch = systemDB.Companies.Where(d => d.Name.Equals("John")).SingleOrDefault();
            if (companySearch != null)
            {
                if (companySearch.EmployeeList != null)
                {
                    systemDB.Companies.Attach(companySearch );
                    companySearch.EmployeeList.Add(employee);
                    systemDB.SaveChanges();

                }

            }
```

I tried that code but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the variable `deviceSearch` as it isn't defined anywhere in the code you have provided. Shouldn't it be `companySearch.EmployeeList.Add(employee);`?

Comment: please are u using database first or code first approach?

Comment: I guess  that is code-first because of the example he posted

Comment: Yes code first approach

Comment: I don't understand how this works at all.  Employee doesn't have a `int CompanyID`.

Comment: *does not (seem to) work* Please be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have your Company and Employee entities defined to have both a navigation property from a Company to the collection of all of its associated Employees and a property from an Employee to its single associated Company, you can accomplish creating a new Employee and associating it with an existing Company from the Employees DB set.

```
[Table("Company")]
public partial class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

[Table("Employee")]
public partial class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}

public partial class Database : DbContext
{
    public Database()
        : base("name=Database")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Employees)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Company)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

Then assuming you already have a Company in the system with an Id of 1, you can do the following:

```
using (var database = new Database())
{
    var company = database.Companies.Find(1);
    if (company != null)
    {
        var employee = new Employee 
        { 
            Name = "John Doe",
            Company = company
        };

        database.Employees.Add(employee);
        database.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

OR...if you are sure that Company Id 1 definitely exists...

```
using (var database = new Database())
{
    var employee = new Employee 
    { 
        Name = "John Doe",
        CompanyId = 1
    };

    database.Employees.Add(employee);
    database.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I think you would need to change your Database Design to accomplish what you want.

```
Employee table
    ID (Primary key) 
    Name
Company table
    ID (Primary key) 
    Name
EmployeeCompany table
    IDCompany (Foreign Key)
    IDEmployee (ForeignKey)
```

This way you will accomplish what you want

Comment: How can a many-to-many association magically solve this problem? That's not only a technical change, but also a logical one that the OP never asked for. Also, you don't show the c# code to deal with this change.